How do I fix the problem of my site not hosting on github
I've uploaded all the necessary files but the pages site doesn't launch
I tried uploading the files by dragging directly into o GitHub rather than choosing the files but now it doesn't even launch the site even though it did before.

Please make ensure that your index.html file is present in the root directory of your repository and check the repository settings to confirm that GitHub Pages is enabled. Also, on top of that make sure you're accessing the correct URL. If the problem persists, try clearing your browser cache or re-uploading your files again.
